# How do you link FFTW using cmake on windows?

Tags: c++, cmake, fftw

I've never been able to get FFTW working properly on windows.

I've used the `lib` executable to succesfully generate the `.dll/.lib` files (i.e. `libfftw3-3f.lib`)

Now when I try to use it I get the `error: LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libfftw3-3.lib'` or `unresolved external ...`

> CMakeLists.txt

```
# allows me to use headers successfully
target_include_directories(${TargetName} PRIVATE "C:\\libs\\fftw")

# tried to add this to perhaps pickup the .lib file(s)
# include_directories("C:\\libs\\fftw")

# tried to add this to perhaps pickup the .lib file(s)
# link_directories("C:\\libs\\fftw")

## tried to add this to perhaps pickup the .lib file(s)
# find_library(FFTW_LIBRARY 
#        NAMES fftw fftw3-3 libfftw3-3 libfftw3-3l libfftw3-3f
#        HINTS "C:\\libs\\fftw"
# )
## at this point, ${FFTW_LIBRARY} = ""
# target_link_libraries(${TargetName} PRIVATE ${FFTW_LIBRARY}) 

target_link_libraries(${TargetName} PRIVATE libfftw3-3)
```

Comment: Did you try to use `target_link_directories`?

Comment: @Evg I tried `link_directories` ill try that one now

Comment: @Evg That didn't work either

Comment: Which error? "Can't open file"?

Comment: `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_fftw_execute referenced in function main
main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d referenced in function main ...`

Comment: My guess: `target_link_libraries(${TargetName} PRIVATE libfftw3-3 libfftw3f-3 libfftw3l-3)`.